# Longtable forces text out of bounds

Tags: graphics, floats, longtable

I have a problem with my page boundaries while using longtable. The text below the longtable is always going out of the bottom page limit. The example is made out of a large report and a situation like this occurs multiple times. I use the longtable environment because the content is auto-generated and it can extend to multiple pages. Also the figure position should be kept to the top of the page and the new section should start after the figure, that's why I can't change the [ht] or remove the \FloatBarrier.

My thought is that LaTeX can't calculate the needed space correctly. Does anyone knows a solution for this problem?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Best regards, Jann

Picture of the problem:

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}      
\usepackage{longtable}      
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{caption}    

\begin{document}

 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text    

\begin{figure}[ht]%
  \center
  \includegraphics{Test.pdf}%
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

\section{TEXT}

    \begin{small}
    
      \begin{longtable}{|T{0.34\textwidth}|T{0.1\textwidth}|T{0.35\textwidth}|T{0.1\textwidth}|}
        \hline 
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Unit} \\ \hline
      \endfirsthead
      \multicolumn{4}{c}
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Unit} \\ \hline
      \endhead
      \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page $\longrightarrow$}} \\ 
      \endfoot
      \endlastfoot
      \texttt{Text} & \texttt{Text} & Text & $\text{s}$ \tabularnewline 
      \texttt{Text} & \texttt{Text} & Text & $\text{s}$  \tabularnewline 
      \texttt{Text} & \texttt{Text} & Text & $\text{s}$ \tabularnewline 
      \hline \hiderowcolors \caption{Text Text}  
      \end{longtable}
    \end{small}
    
 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   

\end{document}
```

Comment: How is the `T` column defined?

Comment: Definition for T: \newcolumntype{T}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your document example is not possible to compile. The preamble is not complete. Missed are some packages and used column type definition. After correcting this, with your document example I can't reproduce your problem. BTW, `small` font size is not an environment but switch (from some font size) to `\small` font size.